# Excel vba - multiple conditions and multiple statements

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA coding and need some help. I'm looking for a code that selects ranges based on the value of differet cells.

In my sheet i have 7 cells that have a formula which give the cell a "X" if i want an range is to be selected:

If I33 = "X" then select A1: S31 (I33 has a formula)

If I34 = "X" then select T1: AH31 (I33 has a formula)

I have 7 of these ....

What I'm looking for; if one or more of I33, I34, i35, I36, I37, I38 or I39 has an "X", the respective area (example A1:S31, there are 7 different ranges) should be selected.

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Why VBA? Use formula!

Comment: I'm going to use the selected ranges to print to pdf and mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim xRangeAdress As Range, rangesAddress() As Range, rangeToSelect As Range, cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X-Sheet") '<== change it as per your actual sheet name
    Set xRangeAdress = ws.Range("I33:I39") '<== set the range with "X" formulas: change "I33:I39" as per your actual needs

    Call SetRangeAddresses(rangesAddress(), ws) ' call the sub you demand the addresses settings to

    For Each cell In xRangeAdress 'loop through "X" cells
        If UCase(cell.Value) = "X" Then Set rangeToSelect = MyUnion(rangeToSelect, rangesAddress(cell.Row - 33 + 1)) ' if there's an "X" then update 'rangeToSelect' range with corresponding range
    Next cell
    rangeToSelect.Select
End Sub


Sub SetRangeAddresses(rangeArray() As Range, ws As Worksheet)
    ReDim rangeArray(1 To 7) As Range '<== resize the array to as many rows as cells with "X" formula

    With ws ' type in as many statements as cells with  "X" formula
        Set rangeArray(1) = .Range("A1:S31")   '<== adjust range #1 as per your actual needs
        Set rangeArray(2) = .Range("T1:AH31")  '<== adjust range #2 as per your actual needs
        Set rangeArray(3) = .Range("AI1:AU31") '<== adjust range #3 as per your actual needs
        Set rangeArray(4) = .Range("AU1:BK31") '<== adjust range #4 as per your actual needs
        Set rangeArray(5) = .Range("BL1:BT31") '<== adjust range #5 as per your actual needs
        Set rangeArray(6) = .Range("BU1:CD31") '<== adjust range #6 as per your actual needs
        Set rangeArray(7) = .Range("CE1:CJ31") '<== adjust range #7 as per your actual needs
    End With
End Sub


Function MyUnion(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set MyUnion = rng2
    Else
        Set MyUnion = Union(rng1, rng2)
    End If
End Function
```

I added comments to let you study and develop his code for your further knowledge

Comment: It seems to work just as it should :-). I thought I had control now, but how can I use the selections and print to .pdf?

Comment: if my answer fulfilled your question then please mark it as accepted. as for "how to print to pdf" you have to start a new question since that doesn't apply to "how to select ranges" which is the current question. in starting a new question you may want to add in all your efforts (show code written so far for the _new_ question) to both have more people likely to help you and have their help more effective

Comment: @user3598756 you left option explicit out of your code block, I went to reformat it for you but its too few characters for me to make the edit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have a different solution (regarding what you need choose one of them):

```
Option Explicit

Function MainFull(Optional WS As Variant) As Range
  If VarType(WS) = 0 Then
    Set WS = ActiveSheet
  ElseIf VarType(WS) <> 9 Then
    Set WS = Sheets(WS)
  End If
  With WS
    Dim getRng As Variant, outRng As Range, i As Long
    getRng = WS.Range("I33:I39").Value
    For i = 1 To 7
      If getRng(i, 1) = "x" Then
        If MainFull Is Nothing Then
          Set MainFull = .Range(Array("A1:S31", "T1:AL31", "AM1:BE31", "BF1:BX31", "BY1:CQ31", "CR1:DJ31", "DK1:EC31")(i - 1)) '<- change it to fit your needs
        Else
          Set MainFull = Union(MainFull, .Range(Array("A1:S31", "T1:AL31", "AM1:BE31", "BF1:BX31", "BY1:CQ31", "CR1:DJ31", "DK1:EC31")(i - 1))) '<- change it to fit your needs
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Function
```

---

```
Function MainArray(Optional WS As Variant) As Variant
  If VarType(WS) = 0 Then
    Set WS = ActiveSheet
  ElseIf VarType(WS) <> 9 Then
    Set WS = Sheets(WS)
  End If
  With WS
    Dim getRng As Variant, outArr() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    getRng = WS.Range("I33:I39").Value
    i = Application.CountIf(WS.Range("I33:I39"), "x")
    If i = 0 Then Exit Function
    ReDim outArr(1 To i)
    For i = 1 To 7
      If getRng(i, 1) = "x" Then
        j = j + 1
        Set outArr(j) = .Range(Array("A1:S31", "T1:AL31", "AM1:BE31", "BF1:BX31", "BY1:CQ31", "CR1:DJ31", "DK1:EC31")(i - 1)) '<- change it to fit your needs
      End If
    Next
  End With
  MainArray = outArr
End Function
```

`MainFull` returns the whole range for all marked ranges while `MainArray` returns an array which holds all ranges which are marked with "x".

**How to use it**:

For `MainFull` you can simply set the range via `Set myRange = MainFull("Sheet1")`. This way it can easily used within another macro (sub) to copy/paste it somewhere.

But if you need to repeat this process for every set range (which is marked by "x") then the second sub is needed like:

```
Dim myRange As Variant
For Each myRange In MainArray("Sheet1")
  ....
Next
```

Then do all the stuff via `myRange`. If you still have any questions, just ask ;)